# Mac OSX: Finder stops displaying shared section

Tags: macos, finder

The finder in Mac OSX (Mountain Lion) suddenly stops showing the shared section. It might show up again in a couple of days or in might not. All completely spontaneous with no apparent cause. Any clues?

Comment: Is there anything to share available in your local network?

Comment: 2 other macs and 2 windows systems all with file sharing enabled

Comment: This could be related to the firewall. You need to set the `NetworkBrowserAgent` to allow all incoming connections. Have you done this?